# Текстовый результат при суммирований чисел

Tags: java, android

```
int vozrast;
String rezultat;
vozrast=31;
rezultat="Мой новый возраст: " + vozrast+1;
```

В этом случае результат будет таковым

> Мой новый возраст: 311

А нужно

> Мой новый возраст: 32

Как это лучше организовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ожидаемое превращается в строку, так как оператор `+` перегружен и может складывать не только числа, но и строки. В вашем случае сперва идет сложение строки с переменной `vozrast`. В итоге получается строка, но она уже думает что `+` дальше означают конкатенацию. Чтобы сначала выполнилось сложение и только потом конкатенация заключитe сложение в скобки

```
rezultat = "Мой новый возраст: " + (vozrast + 1);
```

Comment: Исчерпывающий ответ. Спасибо!

Comment: @androman, да не за что :)